# Why do some use "$\;\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\;$" for definitions?

Tags: notation

Why do some use the equality symbol "$\;\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\;$" for some definitions? For instance,
$$\varepsilon \;\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\; \frac{\Delta(L)}{L}$$

Comment: In order to make a distinction with usage of "=" for **properties** ; example a formula like $S=\frac12$ height $\times$ base does not **define** area $S$ which has been defined elsewhere.

Comment: You will also see definitions given by $:=$ symbol, which finds its origin in computer science languages affectation (even if affectation cannot be reduced to definition), more explicitly, Algol langage (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science))

Comment: You can also see "$\;\stackrel{\Delta}{=}\;$" for definitions. I prefer "$\;:=\;$", though. Much easier to type. :)

Comment: @Blue indeed "$:=$" is better because it make clear what is defined by what, the other symbols are symmetric. By example, I used sometimes the symbol "$=:$" to define the meaning of a symbol after some algebra in the LHS of $=:$

Comment: A previous similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/659537)

Comment: Merci  beaucoup Jean Marie!

Comment: @Masacroso I always hated that symbol. It’s too phallic for my taste (which is saying a lot considering that’s my preferred sex, lol)

Comment: I type equivalent sign in the search box, and I did not see the Distinguishing definitions from equivalences. – Xander Henderson 1